# JQuery UI selectmenu doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use selectmenu it just doesn't work. When I click on selected option selectmenu doesn't hide. Also it is screen wide even though I set width to 200px.
Here is my code. What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#speed").selectmenu();

   });
</script>

</head>
<body>
        <label for="speed">Choose</label>
        <select name="speed" id="speed" style="width: 200px">
           <option>Slower</option>
           <option>Slow</option>
           <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
           <option>Fast</option>
           <option>Faster</option>
        </select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the example on https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ , there is a fieldset tag before the label tag, and a form tag

Comment: adding that tag didn't help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use selectmenu() with this version of css, because the css classes are not defined yet in it.

If you use the version of the example (1.11.4) it works correctly.